# min heap program stopped working

Tags: c, data-structures

I am doing a simple minheap program but when size of heap is 4 i get an error program stopped working.
i checked heap size 2,3,5,6,7 program is working fine.

Why am i getting this error only when heapsize is 4?

I am using codeblocks 16.01, windows 10, gcc compiler.

**minHeap.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void MinHeapfy(int A[], int i, int N)
{
    int l,r,temp,smallest;
    l = 2*i;
    r = 2*i + 1;

    if((l<=N) && (A[l]<A[i]))
    {
        smallest = l;
    }
    else
    {
        smallest = i;
    }
    if((r<=N) && (A[r]<A[smallest]))
    {
        smallest = r;
    }
    if(smallest != i)
    {
        temp = A[smallest];
        A[smallest] = A[i];
        A[i] = temp;

        MinHeapfy(A,smallest,N);
    }
}

void BuildHeap(int A[],int N)
{
    int i;
    int f = floor(N/2);
    printf("f %d", f);
    for(i=f;i>=1;i--)
    {
        printf("i %d\n",i);
        MinHeapfy(A,i,N);
    }
}



int main()
{
    int *A,N,T,data,q,i=1;
    scanf("%d",&N);

    A = (int *)calloc(N,sizeof(int));

    for(i=1;i<=N;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&data);
        A[i]=data;
    }
    BuildHeap(A,N);
    for(i=1;i<=N;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",A[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Arrays in c start at offset 0. So your loops should be `for(i=0;i<N;i++)`

Comment: What Holger said. Likewise, your checks should be `l < N` and `r < N`. `N` is an illegal index for arrays of `N` elements.

Comment: yes i got the answer, thanks , it was due to illegal index N.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can share some things that I learned till now:

```
void BuildHeap(int *A, int N);
void MinHeapfy(int *A, int i, int N);
```

In this 2 functions you just send a pointer not an array(difference between int *A and int A[5])

```
int main()
{
    /*here it is better for you to declare like this 
      to see more easier which is which pointer and variable
      (PS: at the moment you don't use q)*/

    int N,T,data,i;//,q
    int *A;

    scanf("%d",&N);

    A = (int *)calloc(N,sizeof(int));

    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&data);
        A[i]=data;
    }
    BuildHeap(A,N);
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",A[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The 2 fors that you use must start from 0 to N

When you write:

A[0] <=> address pointed by A + 0 * sizeof(data type of A)

So 0 is the first address of the array

and the last address is N-1

A[N-1] <=> address pointed by A + (N-1) * sizeof(data type of A)